# Play music remotely via HTTP REST API?

Tags: pi-3, remote, audio-playback

I would like to play files locally on a Raspberry Pi 3 from another devices triggering like this example:

http://rpi3_IP/file1.mp3 and play it on a Pi.

I know there are some distros that can be remotely controlled by apps but not sure if any of them can be controlled by very basic HTTP commands...

My idea is to communicate between my Raspberry Pi 3 and my home automation system, like this:
IF door open THEN play this file on the Pi triggering an HTTP command.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a reply for myself. Volumio can do that and it is very easy to implement and control it remotely.
https://volumio.github.io/docs/API/REST_API.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQTT to send messages/values to the RPi and then use Node.js/Red-Node to execute an action when an MQTT message is received.